xmlrpc.client error on Python 3.13 MacOS (Apple Silicon)
I am trying to solve a question from pythonchallenge level13.
I found an answer online and wanted to test the code on my MacBook(M3).
This is the code that I am running. It's the exact same code from the link above.
import xmlrpc.client

conn = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/phonebook.php")
print(conn.phone("Bert"))

This is the output I get when running the code.
File "/Users/hwkim301/pythonchallenge/13.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(conn.phone("Bert"))
          ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1096, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1435, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
        self.__host,
    ...<2 lines>...
        verbose=self.__verbose
        )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1140, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1156, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1316, in parse_response
    while data := stream.read(1024):
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/gzip.py", line 326, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/gzip.py", line 529, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/gzip.py", line 498, in _read_gzip_header
    last_mtime = _read_gzip_header(self._fp)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/gzip.py", line 458, in _read_gzip_header
    raise BadGzipFile('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\n\n')

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it? I know xmlrpc is already installed in python3.
I am using Python 3.13 and I installed the macOS version from the official Python page.
My ~/.bash_profile looks like this.
  1 PS1='hwkim301:\w macbook\$ '
  2 eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
  3 export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
  4 export CLICOLOR=1
  5 alias ls='ls -G'
  6 alias ll='ls -lG'
  7 touch ~/.hushlogin
  8 
  9 # Added by OrbStack: command-line tools and integration
 10 # Comment this line if you don't want it to be added again.
 11 # source ~/.orbstack/shell/init.bash 2>/dev/null || :
 12 
 13 # Setting PATH for Python 3.13
 14 # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
 15 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/bin:${PATH}"
 16 export PATH

I also tested the exact same code on my desktop (Dell Inspiron) on Windows and It ran fine.
How can I get the code running on my MacBook?
I tried reinstalling Python 3.13 and running the code using the built-in Python 3.9.6 on macOS. The results were the same. I expected that deleting and reinstalling Python 3.13 would work, but it did not. It seems odd that my less powerful Dell desktop doesn't have any problems running the code.
Any thoughts on the problem would be helpful.

I found out that other people were having the same problem that I had. It has nothing to do with Python 3.13 or the xmlrpc module. As of now, it looks like level 13 of Pythonchallenge can't be solved using the xmlrpc module. If you are having the same problem, I would recommend checking the forum on Pythonchallenge.
